# Is $E$ path connected $\implies \overline{E}$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ a path connectedness open set. Is $\overline{E}$ connected ? (where $\overline{E}$ is the closure of $E$). I tried to prove that it's true, but I don't get anything, may be it's false.

I don't want any proof, I just want to know if it's correct or not. And if it's not, do you have a counterexample ?

Comment: But be aware that $\overline{E}$ need not be path-connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path-connectedness implies connectedness, and the closure of a connected set is connected.

Comment: great :-) thanks,

Answer (score 3):

path-connected -> connected -> closure connected

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To prove that a subspace $X \subset Y$ is connected, it is sufficient to prove that any continuous function $X \to \{0,1 \}$ is constant. So, take a continuous function $f : \overline{E} \to \{0,1 \}$, prove that $f_{|E}$ is constant and conclude that $f$ has to be constant.

It is worth noticing that connectedness instead of path-connectedness is sufficient to conclude.